# tf.data.Dataset caching causes memory error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dataset, gpu

I've been trying to use `cache()` to speed up my training but every time after ~300 iterations I get an error that I've tried to allocate more memory than available (I'm doing the training in a kaggle notebook so my resources are 13GB RAM and 16GB gpu memory). My dataset is about 5GB in total and I'm loading it like this:

```
paths = glob(str(Path(BASE_TRAIN) / '*' / '*'), recursive = True)
ds_train = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(Path(BASE_TRAIN) / '*' / '*'))
ds_train = (ds_train.shuffle(len(paths))
       .map(load_image, num_parallel_calls = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
       .cache()
       .batch(64)
       .prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE))
```

This is my `load_image` function:

```
def load_image(file_path):
    image = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    image = tf.io.decode_jpeg(image, channels = 3, dct_method = 'INTEGER_ACCURATE')
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (224, 224), method = 'nearest')
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.0
    return image, image
```

(I'm returning `image, image` because I'm working on a Convolutional Autoencoder)
So my question is is this just an issue that I don't have enough resources to use `cache()` with the dataset of my size or am I doing something wrong that can be corrected in order for me to use it?

Comment: Are you certain it's `cache()` causing the issue?

Comment: I'm pretty sure cause when I remove it the training continues as it should.

Comment: Can you try if using a file instead of memory fixes it `dataset.cache("/path/to/file")`?

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs regardless of data type and can be reproduced under `tennsorflow==2.12` on Google Colab with this snippet:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import psutil

IMG_SHAPE = (224,224,3)

def gen_img(shape=IMG_SHAPE):
  while True:
    img = np.random.randint(0,256,size=IMG_SHAPE)
    lab = np.random.randint(0,10)
    yield (img,lab)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
      gen_img,
      output_signature=(
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=IMG_SHAPE, dtype=tf.int32),
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32)
      )
)
# !rm ./my_cached_dataset*
ds = ds.take(int(1e6)).cache('./my_cached_dataset')

for i,(img,lab) in enumerate(ds):
  if i%1000==0:
    print(psutil.virtual_memory())
```

```
svmem(total=13613314048, available=10850852864, percent=20.3, used=2434076672, free=7559041024, active=906129408, inactive=4844064768, buffers=64012288, cached=3556184064, shared=14835712, slab=175853568)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=10521788416, percent=22.7, used=2747904000, free=6077923328, active=906240000, inactive=6315372544, buffers=64040960, cached=4723445760, shared=14835712, slab=208736256)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=10236280832, percent=24.8, used=3028914176, free=4544966656, active=906436608, inactive=7809634304, buffers=64090112, cached=5975343104, shared=14835712, slab=246456320)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=9950810112, percent=26.9, used=3314257920, free=3025170432, active=906653696, inactive=9291436032, buffers=64151552, cached=7209734144, shared=14835712, slab=283971584)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=9844416512, percent=27.7, used=3420823552, free=1683304448, active=906842112, inactive=10606862336, buffers=64253952, cached=8444932096, shared=14835712, slab=321568768)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=9564856320, percent=29.7, used=3700228096, free=177987584, active=906969088, inactive=12075044864, buffers=64327680, cached=9670770688, shared=14835712, slab=358412288)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=9306722304, percent=31.6, used=3958439936, free=146292736, active=901074944, inactive=12113723392, buffers=63893504, cached=9444687872, shared=14835712, slab=358301696)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=9062457344, percent=33.4, used=4202684416, free=158429184, active=917561344, inactive=12082872320, buffers=72581120, cached=9179619328, shared=14835712, slab=358375424)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=8777129984, percent=35.5, used=4488118272, free=169414656, active=904667136, inactive=12088320000, buffers=72642560, cached=8883138560, shared=14835712, slab=354672640)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=8411869184, percent=38.2, used=4853186560, free=150278144, active=909676544, inactive=12105269248, buffers=72720384, cached=8537128960, shared=14835712, slab=350715904)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=8128163840, percent=40.3, used=5137051648, free=133636096, active=915939328, inactive=12118491136, buffers=72781824, cached=8269844480, shared=14835712, slab=347828224)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=7969546240, percent=41.5, used=5295702016, free=160477184, active=918454272, inactive=12089397248, buffers=72687616, cached=8084447232, shared=14835712, slab=347074560)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=7750971392, percent=43.1, used=5514133504, free=167464960, active=916754432, inactive=12085276672, buffers=72437760, cached=7859277824, shared=14835712, slab=345300992)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=7436046336, percent=45.4, used=5829201920, free=149508096, active=917139456, inactive=12106104832, buffers=71725056, cached=7562878976, shared=14835712, slab=340811776)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=7164350464, percent=47.4, used=6100865024, free=151359488, active=909705216, inactive=12117614592, buffers=71786496, cached=7289303040, shared=14835712, slab=336646144)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=7000424448, percent=48.6, used=6264721408, free=135954432, active=911155200, inactive=12132208640, buffers=71827456, cached=7140810752, shared=14835712, slab=336437248)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=6680399872, percent=50.9, used=6584848384, free=146821120, active=912543744, inactive=12124856320, buffers=71852032, cached=6809792512, shared=14835712, slab=330891264)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=6393442304, percent=53.0, used=6871932928, free=145813504, active=902815744, inactive=12138004480, buffers=66830336, cached=6528737280, shared=14835712, slab=326344704)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=6077788160, percent=55.4, used=7187349504, free=165052416, active=881020928, inactive=12147015680, buffers=56410112, cached=6204502016, shared=14835712, slab=320839680)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=5785300992, percent=57.5, used=7479914496, free=145641472, active=876072960, inactive=12173660160, buffers=49553408, cached=5938204672, shared=14835712, slab=317030400)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=5493518336, percent=59.6, used=7771713536, free=158281728, active=876392448, inactive=12165447680, buffers=48906240, cached=5634412544, shared=14848000, slab=312012800)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=5238542336, percent=61.5, used=8026632192, free=160530432, active=873414656, inactive=12168273920, buffers=48508928, cached=5377642496, shared=14868480, slab=308314112)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=5043695616, percent=63.0, used=8221499392, free=150355968, active=868638720, inactive=12184272896, buffers=48365568, cached=5193093120, shared=14884864, slab=306577408)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=4774567936, percent=64.9, used=8490598400, free=158916608, active=868274176, inactive=12179013632, buffers=47935488, cached=4915863552, shared=14909440, slab=302632960)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=4449402880, percent=67.3, used=8815779840, free=166301696, active=864616448, inactive=12180488192, buffers=47587328, cached=4583645184, shared=14909440, slab=297308160)
svmem(total=13613314048, available=4106461184, percent=69.8, used=9158742016, free=138387456, active=860499968, inactive=12217360384, buffers=47394816, cached=4268789760, shared=14913536, slab=291655680)
```

See [this gist notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/maciejskorski/1fe224a0d6664813da16fbdbca9dd1e2/oom_tfdataset_cache.ipynb).

At the moment, it is not clear to me if this is one more bug (`tf.dataset` was bit rushed and has received many bug reports on memory issues) or if we are missing some manual instructions. I will update the answer once I have more clarity on the problem.